# if block is not executing in javascript

Tags: javascript

So i was learning node js in which i got stuck in the if block statement.
Below is the code snippet :-

```
routes.post("/cart", (req, res, next) => {
  const prodId = req.body.productId;
  console.log("product Id in cart.js is :- ", prodId);

  let productList = [];
  let cartList = [];
  fs.readFile(productListDatapath_dir, (err, data) => {
    if (!err) productList = JSON.parse(data);
  });

  fs.readFile(cartDatapath_dir, (err, data) => {
    if (!err) {
      cartList = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(cartList);
      cartList.forEach((product) => {
        console.log("productId :- ", product.Id);
        console.log("proId:- ", prodId);
        console.log("productId :- ", typeof product.Id);
        console.log("proId:- ", typeof prodId);
        if (product.Id === prodId) {
          console.log("If block executed");
          product.quantity += 1;
        } else {
          console.log("else block executed");
          productList.forEach((element) => {
            // console.log('elementId :- ',element.Id );
            // console.log('proId:- ',prodId);
            if (element.Id === prodId) {
              console.log("ProductList if block executed");
              cartList.push(element);
            }
          });
        }
        // res.render("./shop/product-detail.ejs", { title: "Product Details", product, });
      });
    }
    // Writing the content of temporary array into the productData.json file
    fs.writeFile(cartDatapath_dir, JSON.stringify(cartList), (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  });
  res.redirect("/cart");
});
module.exports = routes;
```

Below is the output on the terminal :-
[image: terminal output picture]

Could some one tell me why is if block statement is not executing even after both value and datatype is same???

```
if (product.Id === prodId) {
    console.log("If block executed");
    product.quantity += 1;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Check that their length is the same. (A trailing space would cause a problem, for example.) If so, iterate over each character and check their code points. Something isn't equal somewhere.

Comment: As the previous comment. There might me a trailing space, or a zerowidth character in there somewhere.

Comment: along with the previous comments, also try checking the `typeof` variable, `===` checks for type as well

Comment: have you tried to trim your string? prodId.trim()